# iPhone Development Provisioning Assistant Step 3 public/private Key problem

Tags: iphone, provisioning

Hi I am using the Development Provisioning Assistant

At Step 3: Verify your private and public keys in Keychain Access, I have the "iPhone Developer: XXXXXXX" certificate in the Keychains->login, but I can't find any keys. If I click Category->Keys I see nothing.

What should I do to make it has the private key and public key there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keys should be generated when you create the "Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority" with Keychain Access. Should be a prior step.

When you are logged into the "iPhone Developer Program Portal", download and read the "Program Portal User Guide" which is on the right. Following that guide solves a lot of problems.

Comment: Apple should really include that step at the development provisioning assistant

Comment: absolutely.  I am so frustrated by the whole experience - I am ready to toss my mac out the window.

Comment: absolutely tim. I'm also quite frustrated working with Apple things.

Comment: They have added videos of the process in the "Portal". You should find the under the "User Guide" which still is up to the right.