# iPhone provisioning problem: Public/Private Key

Tags: iphone, provisioning

provisioning problem again.

Refering to my question:
[iPhone Development Provisioning Assistant Step 3 public/private Key problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609486/iphone-development-provisioning-assistant-step-3-public-private-key-problem)

I have another mac computer which needs to install the certificate.

This page described how to "Saving your Private Key and Transferring to other Systems":
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/certificates/team/howto.action

The "HowTo" only shows the transfer of private key, is there any need to transfer the public key too? If so, how to transfer it?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh after a series of fixing here & there, finally got the application onto the iPhone. And there is no need to transfer the public key to the other machines.