# iPhone dev: Get keys (public / private)

Tags: iphone

I'm using another computer than normal to do iPhone dev.

Now I'm trying to get my apps onto my iPhone, but fail with the certificates, keys and stuff.
Refer to this thread: [iPhone provisioning problem: Public/Private Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613719/iphone-provisioning-problem-public-private-key)

Actually I'm able to download my cert no problem from Apple's site, but how would I get at the keys needed? (private, public), I see no way of getting them...

Comment: willcode: It looks as access to the first computer would be a must here, and I'm not able to access it.
So I'm currently following this page:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/manage/certificates/team/howto.action
I get to "Submitting a Certificate Signing Request for Approval", but in the first step "After creating a CSR, log in to the iPhone Provisioning Portal and navigate to ‘Certificates’ > ‘Development’ and click ‘Add Certificate’.", there is no"Add Certificate" button on the page! On that page (Certificate->Development) I can actually see my certificate created earlier this year(+dl it)

Answer (score 0):

I did this the other day and it is easy as pie!
Apple even has a [guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices/devices.html) on how to do it! You want the very last section, Managing Your Digital Identities.